# Поставить точки перед заглавными буквами. Node js, RegExp

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, node.js

Не силен в регулярках. Задача стоит такая: если перед заглавной буквой есть пробельный символ то поставить перед этим символом точку (весь текст на кириллице). 
Смог придумать только так, но это точно не правильно:

```
let reg = new RegExp('\s[А-Я]', 'g');
for (let i = 0; i<reg.length; i++){
 string.replace(reg[i], '.' + reg[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var s = "Не силен в регулярках Задача стоит такая Смог придумать только так"
console.log(s.replace(/\s[А-ЯЁ]/g, ".$&"))
```

Comment: Спасибо, я тоже решил таким способом:let reg = new RegExp('\s[А-Я]', 'g');
    let matches = string.match(reg);
    for (let i = 0; i<matches.length; i++){
     string.replace(matches[i], '.' + matches[i]);
    }, но Ваше код правильнее.

Comment: @Iryna, про `Ё` не забывай в регулярках.